# How to show the div elements inside the javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal is when I click a button, a javascript function will be called. Inside the javascript function are div tags/elements and I want to show them like a pop up.

JavaScript:

```
$("#button").click(
   openPopUP();
);

function openPopUP(){
 var window = "<div class = 'box'>";
 window += "Will be display as a pop up";
 window += "</div>";
}
```

When I click the  button, I know that the function was called but the box/window does not appear on my html page. Help!

Comment: look at jQuery UI's [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) widget

Comment: Your code does nothing other than creating a string variable called window

Comment: then what do i do to show the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <body>

    <div id="name">backtrack</div>
<button onClick="popUp();">click here</button>


</body>
```

and java script is

```
   function popUp(){
    var popup = document.createElement('div');
    popup.className = 'popup';
    popup.id = 'test';
    var cancel = document.createElement('div');
    cancel.className = 'cancel';
    cancel.innerHTML = 'close';
    cancel.onclick = function (e) { popup.parentNode.removeChild(popup) };
    var message = document.createElement('span');
    message.innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
    popup.appendChild(message);                                    
    popup.appendChild(cancel);
    document.body.appendChild(popup);
    }
```

and fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WGPhG/6/

Comment: thank you. this one nailed it. i just have to fiddle with it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your HTML contents that need to be displayed as a pop up window.

```
<div id="popup">
<!-- Your content here as pop up -->  
</div>
```

Then use [JQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#popup" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      $( "#popup" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not doing anything to show div

see http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

[documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

to show div you can use

replace your variable to `win` instead of `window`

```
$('body').append(win);
```